# Creating and using streams in iOS 5

Tags: ios, json

Bear with me please, I'm a new programmer. (things I say might not make sense)

I'm trying to create an inputStream and outPut stream so that I can write to it using JSON objects elsewhere in the class...

I wanted to know if I'm doing it right. Currently, I'm opening the streams in -(id)init{}

```
 -(id)init{
_isNetworkAvailable = FALSE;
//kCFAllocatorDefault is the same thing as Null
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFStringRef)requestURL, port, &readStream, &writeStream);

NSInputStream *inputStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *)readStream;
NSOutputStream *outputStream = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
[inputStream setDelegate:self];
[outputStream setDelegate:self];
[inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[inputStream open];
[outputStream open];
//There should really be some checking going on here, but we're going to forget it for now
//Call some checking method
_isNetworkAvailable = TRUE;

return self;
 }
```

My question is: is this the right way to handle something like this? Should I declare NSInputStream and NSOutputStream elsewhere?

Why do I have to cast my CFStreams as NSStreams?

Comment: Because `CFStream`s are a C type, and `NSStream`s are an Objective-C type. If you want to use the C API in Core Foundation for `CFStream`s, go ahead. But don't expect to use `NSStream` methods on a `CFStream`.

Comment: @Linuxios they are toll-free bridged. See: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1652/_index.html.

Comment: @idz: I know. But to use the tool-free bridging, you still need to cast it using the `(__bridge NSThing)someCFThing` syntax.

Comment: @Linuxios, OK, that just wasn't very clear from your comment (e.g. you did not mention casting and "don't expect to use `NSStream` methods on a `CFStream`" could be taken to imply that it would not work).

Comment: @idz: Thanks for telling me that. I ment you can't use `NSStream` methods *directly* on a `CFStream`. That's all.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, it makes more sense now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some testing, this was the proper way of creating streams.
CFStreams are cast to NSStreams because NSStreams are obj-c native and provide more options and flexibility with use. NSStream is actually based on CFStream (which is a wrapper on BSD sockets).

This code should always be run asynchronously, as far as I can tell, or you'll see some hanging during runtime.